# ES6 Method to deduplicate keys in JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have two objects, one containing the existing data for my application and another which is data to import. In actuality the objects will be considerably larger and more complex, but the idea is to deduplicate the data and find which keys from the "New Data" object need to be merged into the local data set.

I don't need advice on how to merge the objects, but rather I need to know how to get a list of the UUIDs that exist only in the new data set so that I can manually import the data in a later step based on those UUIDs.

I know I could do this with crazy for loops, but what's a good ES6 way to do this?

Thanks very much

**Existing Data:**

```
{
    Item1: {
        title: 'demo1',
        uuid: 2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255
    },
    Item2: {
        title: 'demo2',
        uuid: fbe9bfbf-1c61-45bb-94d0-2983328a5e74
    },
}
```

**New Data to Import:**

```
{
    Item1: {
        title: 'demo1',
        uuid: 2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255
    },
    Item2: {
        title: 'demo3',
        uuid: 10b216d4-d354-42b9-8c53-f6bb9e8f0079
    },
}
```

Comment: Filter or reduce? Or this: http://2ality.com/2014/01/object-assign.html

Comment: Thank you. I've already investigated the methods and am not yet clear on how I can use them here, coming in with a pre-ES6 mindset. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to get array of `uuid` from new data?

Comment: @NenadVracar yes, but only the UUIDs that don't exist in the original data set. In this case, only UUID `10b216d4-d354-42b9-8c53-f6bb9e8f0079` would be in the array.

Comment: create a `new Set(items.map(item => item.uuid))` and `filter(item => !set.has(item.uuid))`. If you don't want to use a `Set`, use an `Array` and `filter(item => array.indexOf(item.uuid) === -1)`

Comment: `let uuids = new Set(Object.values(obj).map(v => v.uuid).concat([...new Set(Object.values(newValues).map(v => v.uuid))]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get arrays of uuid's from both object using `Object.keys()` and `map()` and then filter new data keys with old one using `filter()` and `includes()`

```js
var obj = {"Item1":{"title":"demo1","uuid":"2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255"},"Item2":{"title":"demo3","uuid":"10b216d4-d354-42b9-8c53-f6bb9e8f0079"}}
var old = {"Item1":{"title":"demo1","uuid":"2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255"},"Item2":{"title":"demo2","uuid":"fbe9bfbf-1c61-45bb-94d0-2983328a5e74"}}

var newKeys = Object.keys(obj).map(e => obj[e].uuid)
var oldKeys = Object.keys(old).map(e => old[e].uuid)

var result = newKeys.filter(e => !oldKeys.includes(e));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks very much Nenad Vracar. This solved my problem very succinctly. So that posterity has the best available answer though, I'm not going to mark any response an answer just yet. I will come back later today to mark one. Thanks again!

Comment: @Slapbox No problem, glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to workout what you want, the property names `item1`, `item2` would be best as array indexes as it would reduce complexity. The following adds new items , eg `item3` when new uuids are found.

```js
    const a = {
        Item1: { title: 'demo1', uuid: "2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255"},
        Item2: { title: 'demo2', uuid: "fbe9bfbf-1c61-45bb-94d0-2983328a5e74"}
    }
    
    const b = {
        Item1: { title: 'demo1', uuid: "2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255"},
        Item2: { title: 'demo3', uuid: "10b216d4-d354-42b9-8c53-f6bb9e8f0079"}
    }
    const findIn = (obj,cb) => { for(let i in obj){ if (cb(obj[i],i) === true) return obj[i] } };
    for(var i in b){
        if(!findIn(a,obj => obj.uuid === b[i].uuid)){
            const pName = Object.keys(a).pop();
            const newPropName = pName.substr(0,4) + (Number(pName.substr(4)) + 1);
            a[newPropName] = Object.assign({},b[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(a)
```

Remember to use use `getOwnPropertyNames()` or perform a `hasOwnProperty()` if there are addition enumerable properties you do not wish to search.

A safer version but uses more resources.

```js
    const a = {
        Item1: { title: 'demo1', uuid: "2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255"},
        Item2: { title: 'demo2', uuid: "fbe9bfbf-1c61-45bb-94d0-2983328a5e74"}
    }
    
    const b = {
        Item1: { title: 'demo1', uuid: "2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255"},
        Item2: { title: 'demo3', uuid: "10b216d4-d354-42b9-8c53-f6bb9e8f0079"}
    }

function appendNewItems(obj1,obj2){
    const objKeys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
    const objKeys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
    const findIn = (obj,cb) => { for(let i of objKeys1){ if (cb(obj[i], i) === true) return obj[i] } };
    for(var i of objKeys2){
        if(!findIn(a,obj => obj.uuid === b[i].uuid)){
            const pName = Object.keys(a).pop();
            const newPropName = pName.substr(0, 4) + (Number(pName.substr(4)) + 1);
            a[newPropName] = Object.assign({}, b[i]);
            // must add the new property name or you could get duplicates
            objKeys1.push(newPropName);
        }
    }
}

appendNewItems(a,b);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example for using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const existingData = {
  Item1: {
    title: 'demo1',
    uuid: '2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255'
  },
  Item2: {
    title: 'demo2',
    uuid: 'fbe9bfbf-1c61-45bb-94d0-2983328a5e74'
  }
};

const newData = {
  Item1: {
    title: 'demo1',
    uuid: '2ecc82ba-4e47-4a8d-90ff-c4beb4148255'
  },
  Item2: {
    title: 'demo3',
    uuid: '10b216d4-d354-42b9-8c53-f6bb9e8f0079'
  }
};

const existingUUIDs = new Set(Object.entries(existingData).map(([k, {uuid}]) => uuid));
const newUUIDs = Object.entries(newData).map(([k, {uuid}]) => uuid).filter((uuid) => existingUUIDs.has(uuid));

console.log(newUUIDs);
```